# Почему не работает meta_query?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Есть вот такой код:

```
$term = get_term( $cat, 'product_cat');

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
    'posts_per_page' => 50,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $cat
        )
    )
);

$products = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Всё прекрасно работает, но как только я добавляю `meta_query`, всё перестает работать, `var_dump($products)` показывает, что ни одного свойства товара в массиве нету. В чём может быть проблема?

Нерабочий код:

```
$attributes = $product->get_attributes();
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'ignore_sticky_posts'   => 1,
    'posts_per_page' => 50,
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => $cat,
        )
    ),
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'cena-polotna-banner',
            'value' => '4500'
        )
    )

);

$products = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Далее идет цикл `while`

```
while ( $products->have_posts() ) : $products->the_post();
```

Без `meta_query` выводит товары, как только добавляю — всё пропадает.

Получил атрибуты вот так:

```
$attributes = $product->get_attributes();
```

Вывести по ключу в цикле получилось, но фильтровать отказывается.

Comment: Походу задача не решаемая(

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так задать `meta_query`:

```
'meta_query' => array(
    array(
        'key' => 'cena-polotna-banner',
        'value' => '4500',
        'compare' => '=',
        'type' => 'numeric'
    )
)
```

Comment: "cena-polotna-banner" ["value"]=> string(4) "4500"

вот что var_dump показывает,но сортировка не происходит

Comment: Ну полную ерунду он вводит. У вас синтаксис где-то неправильный, и не такой, как здесь. Вот вывод в отладчике массива, приведенного в ответе: http://take.ms/8IedV Добейтесь, чтобы массив был заполнен правильно.